# D3DXIntersect Ray In Wrong Coords?

Tags: c++, matrix, directx

I use D3DXIntersect() to pick meshes with the cross-hair already, but I'm having trouble using it to detect collision with the ground. I want to shoot a ray straight down so that I can get the distance to the corresponding triangle of a low-poly mesh, but my BOOL "hit" returns false whenever the test is called.

Since I don't have to convert screen coordinates into a ray, I'm starting with the ray's position in world space, converting it model space, and then calling D3DXIntersect().

```
....
//when I want to check collision with the mesh..
D3DXVECTOR3 origin, direction;

//divide the camera location by the scale of the mesh.
origin = D3DXVECTOR3(gCamera->pos().x / meshScale,
 gCamera->pos().y / meshScale, gCamera->pos().z / meshScale); 
direction = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f);  //Tried -1.0 originally

//get the inverse of the mesh's world matrix
D3DXMATRIX inverseWorld;
D3DXMatrixInverse(&inverseWorld, 0, &meshWorld);

//transform the Ray using the inverse matrix
D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&origin, &origin, &inverseWorld);
D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&direction, &direction, &inverseWorld);

//Intersection Test
BOOL hit = 0;
DWORD faceIndex = -1;
float u = 0.0f;
float v = 0.0f;
float dist = 0.0f;
ID3DXBUFFER* allHits = 0;
DWORD numHits = 0;
HR(D3DXIntersect(mMesh, &origin, &direction, &hit,
&faceIndex, &u, &v, &dist, &allHits, &numHits));

if( hit )
{

   //execute code to prove this line executed...
   //change camera position
}
else
{
   //show me the test happened and there wasn't a hit
}
```

I wasn't originally dividing the origin by the mesh scale, but after googling for how to compensate for a scaled mesh, I found an example written in this way. If that's a mistake, please let me know, but even without using the scale and testing on a regular sized mesh, I'm still not getting a hit with the ray.

Does anyone see any mistakes that would keep me from getting hits? Maybe I'm not converting the ray properly?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This function is not very efficient anyway, as even if it uses some form of spatial partitioning, it would have to rebuild that structure every time. You are better off rolling your own collision detection solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Turns out it was an easy mistake. My mesh's world matrix was simply the translation matrix and not the world matrix, i.e. the translation matrix and scaling matrix multiplied together. For anyone else struggling with this technique, just make sure your matrices are correct and the above code should work.